# Proof writing involving cartesian product: $(A \times B) \cap ( B \times A) \ne \varnothing$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Provide necessary and sufficient conditions for this to be true:
$(A \times B) \cap ( B \times A) \ne \varnothing$

I know for this to be true, **$A = B$**, thus **$(A \times B) \cap ( B \times A) \ne \varnothing$.**

But I'm having trouble coming up with a proof for this. Any help? I don't know where to implement that "$A$ needs to equal $B$" for $(A \times B) \cap ( B \times A) \ne \varnothing$  to be true. How would the proof start?

Comment: Consider $A=\{1,2\},B=\{1,3\}$ and find $(A \times B) \cap ( B \times  A)$

Comment: They don't need to be equal. See if you can find a less strong condition.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments indicated with an example, your claim isn't true. See if you can use the following.

$(A\times B)\cap (B\times A)=(A\cap B)^2$.

Proof. Suppose $(x,y)\in (A\times B)\cap (B\times A)$, then $(x,y)\in A\times B$, so that $x\in A$ and $y\in B$, and $(x,y)\in B\times A$ so that $x\in B$ and $y\in A$. Thus $x,y\in A\cap B$, so that $(x,y)\in (A\cap B)^2$.

Now suppose $(x,y)\in (A\cap B)^2$, then $x,y\in A\cap B$, so that $x\in A$ and $y\in B$ and $(x,y)\in A\times B$, but we also have $x\in B$ and $y\in A$, so that $(x,y)\in B\times A$. Thus $(x,y)\in (A\times B)\cap (B\times A)$

Now we have $(x,y)\in (A\times B)\cap (B\times A)\iff (x,y)\in(A\cap B)^2$.
But then
$(A\times B)\cap (B\times A)=(A\cap B)^2$ as desired.

To be honest, this is probably too much to say, but I thought it was a little interesting. Now you just need to conclude.

Comment: If (A×B)∩(B×A)= (A∩B)^2, therefore (A x B) ∩ ( B x A) ≠ ∅? right?

Comment: @Steve What if $(A\cap B)^2=\varnothing$. We've now reduced the problem to when is $(A\cap B)^2$ the null set? Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: I'm still a bit confused with what you are trying to say. Sorry.

Comment: @Steve, since we know $(A\times B)\cap (B\times A)=(A\cap B)^2$, we also know that $(A\times B)\cap (B\times A)=\varnothing \iff (A\cap B)^2=\varnothing$. But $(A\cap B)^2 = \varnothing \iff A\cap B = \varnothing$. So $(A\times B)\cap (B\times A)=\varnothing \iff A\cap B=\varnothing$.

Comment: Ok. I understand that part: (A×B)∩(B×A)=∅ <==> A∩B=∅ but i'm trying to make (A×B)∩(B×A)≠∅ "valid" with a condition and i don't see how that would help.  Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: I think my question was misleading.

Comment: @Steve Right, so if $A\cap B \ne \varnothing$, then you also have $(A\cap B)^2=(A\times B)\cap (B\times A) \ne \varnothing$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29455/discussion-between-steve-and-jgon).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\rm\exists A,B \;s.t. \; (A\times B)\cap (B\times A)\ne\phi\implies \exists (x,y)\in (A\times B),(B\times A)\implies \exists x\in A,B \;and\;y\in B,A$
but it is not necessary that $x\ne y$. So if $A\cap B\ne \phi$ then it is true.

Answer (score 1):

Statement: $A \times B \cap B\times A \neq \varnothing$ is equivalent to $A \cap B \neq \varnothing$.

Proof $\Rightarrow$

$A \times B \cap B\times A \neq \varnothing \Rightarrow \exists (x,y): (x,y) \in A\times B \wedge (x,y) \in B\times A \Rightarrow \exists x,y \in A, B \Rightarrow \exists x,y \in A \cap B \Rightarrow A \cap B \neq \varnothing$

$\Leftarrow$

$A\cap B \neq \varnothing \Rightarrow \exists x \in A\cap B \Rightarrow \exists x : (x,x) \in A \wedge (x,x) \in B \Rightarrow \exists x : (x,x) \in A\times B \cap B \times A \Rightarrow A\times B \cap B \times A \neq \varnothing$

Answer (score 1):

In essence, "Provide necessary and sufficient conditions for" means "simplify".$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\followsfrom}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$

One way to do this is by the following direct calculation, where we first go to the element/logic level by expanding the set theory definitions, then use the laws of logic to simplify, and take it from there.

Note that I'm taking really small steps here for clarity, so this proof is less complex than it might seem at first sight.

$$\calc
    (A \times B) \cap ( B \times A) \;\not=\; \varnothing
\op\equiv\hints{basic property of 'not empty'; LHS contains only pairs}
         \hint{-- with this we go from the set level to the element level}
    \langle \exists x,y :: (x,y) \in (A \times B) \cap ( B \times A) \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{definition of $\;\cap\;$}
    \langle \exists x,y :: (x,y) \in A \times B \;\land\; (x,y) \in B \times A \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{definition of $\;\times\;$, twice}
    \langle \exists x,y :: x \in A \land y \in B \;\land\; x \in B \land y \in A \rangle
\op{\tag{*}\equiv}\hint{logic: reorder conjuncts; split quantifications}
    \langle \exists x :: x \in A \land x \in B \rangle \;\land\; \langle \exists y :: y \in A \land y \in B \rangle
\op{\tag{**}\equiv}\hint{logic: LHS and RHS are equivalent}
    \langle \exists z :: z \in A \land z \in B \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{definition of $\;\cap\;$; basic property of 'not empty'}
    A \cap B \;\not=\; \varnothing
\endcalc$$

The 'logic' steps $\ref{*}$ and $\ref{**}$ are the real simplification steps; the rest is just 'plumbing' to move between set level and element level.

Finally, note that we did not need to pull the $\;A \cap B \;\not=\; \varnothing\;$ rabbit out of a hat up front: it nicely falls out of the calculation.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Sir. I appreciate it.